# first rank or first ranked

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

which is correct:

*Sharif University of Technology*, **the first rank** technical university of Iran

*Sharif University of Technology*, **the first ranked** technical university of Iran

I guess rank could be noun and the first one could be true, but if I must use an adjective, the second could be true

Answer (score 1):

The two are both valid, and to my eye are in fact subtly different.

"First rank" is not exclusive. There may be a number of universities on the first rank, all of the same class. Hence:

"Sharif University of Technology, the first rank technical university of Iran" suggests that S.U.T. is one of the best technical universities (in the world), and of all of those world-first-class universities, it's the only one of its class in Iran.

"First ranked" does actually literally mean "ranked first", that is, it *is* the absolute top.

"Sharif University of Technology, the first ranked technical university of Iran"  then says that S.U.T. is the best technical university in Iran -- but it also has no possible connotation of being one of a number of institutions (including of anywhere else) of the same echelon.

Answer (score 0):

First ranked.

P.S. Regardless of whether or not the first one is grammatically correct, first ranked flows and sounds much better off the tongue. Also, don't forget the 'and.'

*Sharif University of Technology*, the **first ranked** technical university of Iran, Tehran and Iran.

Comment: thanks, the rest was about address which I removed from the question